# PHPWord - set line spacing to "single"

Tags: phpword

I have to generate some word docs with PHP and need to change the line spacing and line height.

Setting the [line height](https://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html#section) is simple, but I have no idea how I change change the line spacing from "multiple" to "single". (I hope I use the right terms here because I got only a german word version...)

I've added a picture to make clear which option I mean...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the spacing styles (including line spacing) with the paragraph style - you just need to define the value in twips... for example:

```
$paragraphOptions = array('space' => array('line' => 1000));
```

This style option seems to be missing from the referenced styles documentation but it is documented in the source code that line spacing is modifiable [Paragraph style src](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/Paragraph.php)

Comment: Hi, this changes the value of the line spacing **height** (the value of  1,08 in the screenshot) but not the line spacing **type** ("mehrfach" in the screenshot)

Comment: yes, the style setting is done in twips as said - as far as I know, you cannot set the line spacing directly with the options you see in word. If you set such a twip value that it will match the options you see in word, the selection is updated there as well... So if you would want to set the line spacing as single, you can just create a test document with paragraph set as single, open the document xml file and check what is the w:line value in this paragraph style and use the same number value in the line spacing style.

Comment: @SidhiCiang you can try with twip value 240 - it seems to match single line spacing for me at least (no idea whether that is related to some other settings like font size or something). And in general you can use it by using the paragraph options (as described in the above answer) with your text addition...

Comment: For the `line` property also has a `rule` property which also has impact to the line spacing:
`array('line' => 180, 'rule' => 'exact')`

Answer (score 0):

Set like code below.

```
array(
'spaceBefore' => 20, // 20 is equivalent to 1pt
'spaceAfter' => 20 // 20 is equivalent to 1pt
)
```

See screenshot as an equivalent in Word

[image: click to see screenshot]